# Pass ID into URL for newform.aspx?

Tags: 2010, display-form, newsfeed, edit-form, document-id

I have a display form and a list web part just below that. When users click "add new item" on that list web part, I would like for the values to automatically be populated.

The url for the diplay form contains `DispForm.aspx?ID=1`, but when I open the NewForm.aspx, I would like to populate a field with that ID automatically. Can I pass that ID into the NewForm or at least into its url where I can retrieve it from there? All it seems to pass in is the list name that the display form is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your settings, the newform.aspx page will either open in a dialog (iframe) or open in a new page.

Here is how I address this issue in my SPELL library: I don't pass the ID in the URL, but instead I run a script on newform.aspx that follows these steps:

1. When the new form opens, check the parent window
2. if the parent exist (dialog), then the ID is included in window.parent.location.href
3. If the parent does not exist (new page), then check the window.referrer

Note: in practice the newform.aspx page might be opened from more than one display forms. So you might need something more sophisticated than just splitting on `ID=`.

Comment: edit: was able to use document.referrer and window.parent.location.href which is what I think you were hinting toward. Thank you for all your help! I'm constantly finding neat tips/tricks on your blog.

Comment: you're welcome :-) You're right, it's parent.location.href, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the ID parameter from query string in Dispform.aspx,  once you have the ID value you can update "Add new Item" link and pass ID from DispForm.aspx.

Please refer to [Parse Query String from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript) to parse URL and get value from Query String.

Comment: Another option would be to hide the default "add new item" link and create a similar copy yourself with your custom URL generated through jQuery.

Comment: I can get the ID (I just split the location url on ID=), but how do I pass that into NewForm on the list web part?

Comment: The second part in my answer talks about that,  update the HREF property for "Add New Item" hyperlink,  make it to http://sp/sites/site/list/NewForm.aspx?ID=value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for that link! It changed the href to what I needed, but the onclick action for that overrides the new url I have given it when it opens a new form on that page. I am doing some testing to see if I can figure out how to get over that.

Comment: try adding target=_blank attribute to the link,  I think the default SharePoint add new item link calls up another javascript function to load the form in a pop up window.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: I disabled the "open in new dialog" on the list, but the url still has a different event that is telling it to open up a different url which has its own parameters. Can I add the parameters to the newform using that event?